# How to define what DatabaseGenerated.Computed should compute?

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1, code-first, calculated-columns

I am just doing my first steps with EF CodeFirst, especially with dataAnnotations.
Now I'm doing my best to understand the "DatabaseGenerated" attribute.
What I know so far:

- using this attribute gives me three options to handle creation of a property value: Computed, Id and None.
- using this attribute means, that the property can not be updated manually - it is done by the database

So - as I can imagine what happens when using th "Id" option, I have no idea what happens when using "Computed" option. I red that this should tell the db to compute the field value.

For example: field "*sum*" = field "*price*" + field "*shipping*".

But how can I use that in that way? I looked around and did not find any examples. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use EF to tell the database how to compute the column -- you can only tell EF that the column is database generated so it should be retrieved from the database for your use in code.

To control how the database computes the column you have to manually instruct it either outside of EF or in your database initialization logic.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("RAW SQL HERE");
}
```

Your SQL (MS T-SQL) might look like this ([more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)):

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (a int, b int, c int, x float, 
   y AS CASE x 
         WHEN 0 THEN a 
         WHEN 1 THEN b 
         ELSE c 
      END)
```

For SQL here's some info about Computed Colums:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx

Also for reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193958.aspx